# Haskell curried function types

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm a little confused by types returned by `curry` and `uncurry` functions:

```
Prelude> let pairMax (a,b) = if a > b then a else b
Prelude> :t pairMax
pairMax :: Ord a => (a, a) -> a
Prelude> let pairMaxCurried = curry pairMax
Prelude> :t pairMaxCurried 
pairMaxCurried :: () -> () -> ()
```

I don't understand why the curried function's type consists only of Unit types. Trying to apply `pairMaxCurried` unsurprisingly results in an error:

```
Prelude> pairMaxCurried 1 2

<interactive>:10:16:
    No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the first argument of `pairMaxCurried', namely `1'
    In the expression: pairMaxCurried 1 2
    In an equation for `it': it = pairMaxCurried 1 2
```

while currying and applying in the same line is fine:

```
Prelude> (curry pairMax) 1 2
2
```

The same goes for `uncurry`:

```
Prelude> let twoMax a b = if a > b then a else b
Prelude> :t twoMax
twoMax :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> let twoMaxUncurried = uncurry twoMax
Prelude> :t twoMaxUncurried
twoMaxUncurried :: ((), ()) -> ()
```

Declaring explicit type doesn't help:

```
Prelude> let pairMaxCurried = (curry pairMax) :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t pairMaxCurried 
pairMaxCurried :: () -> () -> ()
```

**Question 1.** Why is the type not correctly inferred?

**Question 2.** Is there a way to bind curried/uncurried function to a name while preserving the correct type?

Comment: Can not reproduce with GHC 7.10.2. What version of GHC are you using? The MR should be off by default... (in GHCi)

Comment: @chi The assumption that people are using ghc7.8+ or 7.10+ is generally false. A lot of people install Haskell from the repositories of their distro. AFAIK Ubuntu is still using [haskell platform 2013](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/haskell-platform) which still uses ghc 7.6.x. I believe the MR is off by default only from 7.8+